# Не зайти в AdSense

Tags: реклама, google-adsense

Вот уже 2 дня не войти в аккаунт AdSense. Выводит следующую ошибку:

[image: Номер скрыт намеренно]

И не пойму, это у них что-то отвалилось, или мой аккаунт заблокировали? Пробовал разные браузеры, разные компьютеры, разные IP -- всё без толку.

P.S.: номер телефона скрыт мною намеренно.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что здесь лучше обратиться напрямую в поддержку Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня та же проблема.
Отчет техподдержки:

> К сожалению, ошибка с которой вы столкнулись, все еще не устранена. Наши инженеры работают над устранением данной неполадки. Данная проблема коснулась многих пользователей, и требует больше времени для ее устранения, в связи с чем, благодарю вас за понимание.

Несмотря на это, выплата пришла в срок.

Comment: Выплаты выплатами, но мне нужно новый сайт добавить :(

Comment: Я тоже youtube аккаунт не могу связать.